# How to use FDIV properly? Assembly

Tags: assembly, average, masm, fpu, x87

I wanted to do a simple hybrid code using 16-bit assembly, masm. 
The goal was for program to calculate average, but I get very wrong output every single time and I don't know why. After fadd operation the result should be in st(0). So fdiv should devide st(0)/size and the result should be stored in st(0), right? So when my input is 1+1+1+1+1, the output should be 1 — not 6.39,516e+33. Did I get something wrong? The sum was always correct so it's problem with fdiv part.

Code in c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C" float f1(float *arr, int);

int main()
{
    int size=5;
    float *array;
        cout << "Give your numbers:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    cin>> *(array+i);

    cout<<"\nAverage = "<< f1(array, size) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Assembly

```
.model SMALL, C

.data

.code

PUBLIC f1
f1 PROC NEAR

    push    BP
    mov     BP, SP      



    mov ax, [bp+6]
    mov cx, ax
    mov ax, [bp+4]
    mov bp, ax
    fld dword ptr [bp]
    dec cl


    Loop1:
    add bp, 4
    fld dword ptr [bp]
    fadd
    loop Loop1

    mov bp, sp
    fdiv dword ptr [bp +6]



    pop BP
    ret

f1 ENDP

.stack
db 100(?)

END
```

Comment: Your size is an integer not a float. `fdiv dword ptr` does a float division. try `fidiv word ptr` instead. PS: learn to use a debuger and forget 16 bit.

Comment: It's worked, thank you